# Multifaceted Patches with structs (matlab)

Tags: matlab

matlab newcomer here.
I have a problem understanding how to use patch() using a structure with given vertices and faces.
It is a simple problem and probably easily solved, but I guess I might need a little inspiration.
I wrote the following example lines after reading through the patch-related Documentations I found:

```
Z = struct('VoV',[0 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 1 1; 0 0 1],'VoF',[1 2 3 4]);
patch(Z);
```

Instead of the wanted quadrangle I recieved the error:

> Error using patch
>
> Unrecognized property VoV for class Patch.

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling an example from the MATLAB help page for [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html#busd9x8-1):

```
clear S
S.Vertices = [2 4; 2 8; 8 4; 5 0; 5 2; 8 0];
S.Faces = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
S.FaceVertexCData = [0; 1];
S.FaceColor = 'flat';
S.EdgeColor = 'red';
S.LineWidth = 2;
figure
patch(S)
```

It looks like the field names you want are `Vertices` and 'Faces' not `VoV` and `FoV`.

Comment: Thank you, dunno  know where I got the idea that the field names don't matter